# How to set a border for an HTML div tag

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to define a border around a div tag in HTML.  In some browsers the border does not appear.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```html
<div id="divActivites" name="divActivites" style="border:thin">
    <textarea id="inActivities" name="inActivities" style="border:solid">
    </textarea> 
</div>
```

How do I set a border for an HTML div tag?

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Try being explicit about all the border properties.  For example:

```
border:1px solid black;
```

See [Border shorthand property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).  Although the other bits are optional some browsers don't set the width or colour to a default you'd expect.  In your case I'd bet that it's the width that's zero unless specified.

Comment: I had to remove the "px" suffix.

Comment: @samis That is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 51):

can use

```
border-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
```

or as shorthand

```
border: 2px solid black
```

Answer (score 28):

As per the W3C:

> Since the initial value of the border styles is 'none', no borders will be visible unless the border style is set.

In other words, you need to set a border style (e.g. `solid`) for the border to show up. `border:thin` only sets the width. Also, the color will by default be the same as the text color (which normally doesn't look good).

I recommend setting all three styles:

```
style="border: thin solid black"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```css
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
```

You can change these as you see fit, though.

Comment: You rock! Thanks for posting this (7 years ago)!

Answer (score 9):

I guess this is where you are pointing at ..

```
<div id="divActivites" name="divActivites" style="border:thin">
    <textarea id="inActivities" name="inActivities" style="border:solid">
    </textarea> 
</div>
```

Well. it must be written as `border-width:thin`

Here you go with the [link (click here)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) check out the different types of Border-styles

you can also set the border width by writing the width in terms of pixels.. (like border-width:1px), minimum width is 1px.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set more fields then just border-width. The style basically puts the border on the page. Width controls the thickness, and color tells it what color to make the border.

```
border-style: solid; border-width:thin; border-color: #FFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .centerImge {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
        height:50%;
    }
 <div>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
<span> <img src="@item.Thumbnail"  class="centerImge" /></span>
  <h3 style="text-align:center">  @item.CategoryName</h3>
}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 4, you can use **[border utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border)** like so.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .border-5 {
    border-width: 5px !important;
  }
</style>

<textarea class="border border-dark border-5">some content</textarea>
```