# how to make a css border for div

Tags: html, css

I used this link [How to set a border for an HTML div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020496/how-to-set-a-border-for-an-html-div-tag) to make a css border for a div tag.

```css
#box {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Sign in
</div>
```

If I put only `border: 10px;` or even `border-right: 5px solid black;` then, there is no border. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please let us know that you at least have any understanding of CSS. Because you're asking two totally different questions here...

Comment: @GerardvanHelden - I am learning from tutorials.

Comment: I copy your code in html page and border work  correctly .

Comment: Well, `border:10px;` doesn't work, indeed. By definition. But `border-right: 5px solid black;` should. Doesn't [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pkbhffhv/) work for you?

Comment: @MrLister - It does not work `border-right: 5px solid black;`.

Comment: You can never just write border:10px; border syntax : border: size(px) type color; this only the valid one.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Its pretty obvious they have zero knowledge of CSS. This is entry level at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border: 10px;` will not work because border requires at least a style because there is no default style, but the default color is black so you don't need the color. so the following will work

```
#box {
    border: 10px solid;
}
```

`border-right: 5px solid black;` is the same as `border-right: 5px solid;` and it does display, only a `div` is a block element and as such takes the entire width of the container (just look at the right side of the page)

Now if you want the border to be directly beside the text you can turn the block element `div` into an `inline-block` element

```
#box {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

Also you can set each border property individually like so

```
#box {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
```

or for just one side like so

```
#box {
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 for borders, you can use following utility classes.

Here’s the list of them:

- [Additive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#additive)
- [Subtractive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#subtractive)
- [Border color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-color)

You can also create your own classes, something like:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .border-10 {
    border-width: 10px !important;
  }
  
  .border-20 {
    border-width: 20px !important;
  }
</style>

<h1>Bootstrap 4 Borders</h1>
<hr />

<div class="border border-dark border-10">
  Sign in
</div>
<br />
<div class="border-right border-primary border-20">
  Sign in
</div>
```